# Проверка наличия свойства css

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть кнопка сворачивания блока, нужно чтобы при ее нажатии проверялись свойство display самого блока и менялся aria-label кнопки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(div.style.display === 'block'){
    btn.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Значение');
  }
});
```

Если конечно у вас display задан через style. Если через css, то условие будет такое:

```
if(getComputedStyle(div).display === 'block') ...
```